# Pass data between ViewController without Segues

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new to swift development and have some problems understanding how to pass data between ViewController.

I want to build a simple music player app which has three views (*Player*, *Playlists*, *Tracks*).

At start the *Player* is shown to the user. From there the user can press a button and the *Playlists* view come up. Now he can select a playlist and the next view *Tracks* is displayed.

If he press on a track he gets back to the *Player* view and the track is playing. So I need to pass my track to my PlayerViewController.

Currently I'm using Segues to display each ViewController.
Player -> Playlists -> Tracks -> Player

But this will initialise the *Player* again which means that values/variables get reset. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Explain how you get from Player to Playlists to Tracks (each of them).

Comment: I have completed a similar musicPlayer application.I have many local music files and I create a musics array to save the URL, title,album,artist of the musics. The playlist View is a tableView, each row contains a music name and album.When I click the cell, it will present the playViewcontroller and will pass the URL of the music.

Comment: How are you presenting the next ViewController? If you're not sure, take a look at this guide.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html

Comment: @Stefan currently I'm using segues to display the next ViewController; Player -> Playlists -> Tracks -> Player; The problem is that If I return from segue to the Player ViewController again all changed value gets reset.

Comment: If you present the next view controller modally, the view controller under it will persist.

Comment: @Marlon: set a storyboardId for the target viewcontroller then before push set the object which you need to pass to target viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting from view controller B to view controller C by saying `present`, then view controller C can speak to view controller B as its `presentingViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***Unwind segues*** to pass data i guess they can help you out.

```
    An unwind segue (sometimes called exit segue) can be used to navigate 
    back through push, modal or popover segues (as if you popped the navigation
     item from the navigation bar, closed the popover or dismissed the modally
     presented view controller). On top of that you can actually unwind through
     not only one but a series of push/modal/popover segues, e.g. "go back"multiple steps in your navigation hierarchy with a single unwind action.When you perform an unwind segue, you need to specify an action, which is an action method of the view controller you want to unwind to.
        
//ViewControllerA:

import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    
    var dataRecieved: String? {
        willSet {
            labelOutlet.text = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOutlet:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButtonOutlet: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
        controller.dataPassed = labelOutlet.text
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }

    // segue ViewControllerB -> ViewControllerA
    @IBAction func unwindToThisView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ViewControllerB {
            dataRecieved = sourceViewController.dataPassed
        }
    }

}

//ViewControllerB

import UIKit

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldOutlet: UITextField!
    var dataPassed : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFieldOutlet.text = dataPassed
  
        textFieldOutlet.delegate = self
    }

    // UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // User finished typing (hit return): hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        dataPassed = textField.text
    }

}
```

//From the Return Button click control and drag to exit of the viewcontrollerB as show in the image.

[image]

Comment: Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score -1):

To pass data between View Controllers, have this block in your code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let feed = segue.destination as! SecondViewControllerName

    feed.variableinsecondviewcontroller = variableincurrentviewcontroller
}
```

If that didn't help, you might need to elaborate on what exactly you want with your code...

Comment: Currently i'm using this method in my code. The problem is that If I return from segue to the FirstViewController (Player) all changed value gets reset.

Comment: What you could either do is embed a View within your ViewController to prevent this, or create another segue data transfer for going back to the First View Controller. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use struct class and access your object any where using the stuct object
 Like this

struct SomeStruct { var name: String init(name: String) { self.name = name } } var aStruct = SomeStruct(name: "Bob") var bStruct = aStruct // aStruct and bStruct are two structs with the same value! bStruct.name = "Sue" println(aStruct.name) // "Bob" println(bStruct.name) // "Sue"